# Lambda expression does not iterate over int[]

Tags: java, lambda

While practicing lambda expressions in Java 8 I found that forEach does not loop through all elements of int[]. For e.g.

```
int[] ints = new int[5];
Arrays.asList(ints).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
```

Output is :

```
[I@573fd745  // this is also what I get if print the array directly in console
```

It does not matter if array is initialized like this.

```
int[] ints2 = {1,2,3,4,5};
Arrays.asList(ints2).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
```

Output is:

```
[I@4f2410ac
```

But if I use simple for loop, I get correct results

```
int[] ints = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ints[i]);
}
```

Output is

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Also both lambdas work fine for Integer[] & String[]

```
Integer[] integers = new Integer[5];
Arrays.asList(integers).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
```

Output is

```
null   // similarly for String[]
null
null
null
null
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening over here? Why forEach loops through elements of Integer[] but through int[]?

Comment: Use an `IntStream`. `IntStream.of(ints).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));`

Comment: or .forEach(System.out::println)